# Not getting element by ID dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get the id of one of many of IDs. They each have the id "row*col*"where '*' is equal to a number. They elements are all divs.

The problem comes in here where I am getting the element by id. I have tested it by finding the function by typing it in but I need to have it find hat specific div. I know it's very inefficient to do it like this, but right now I am not able to alter it, unless that is the only option.

```
var tID = "col" + c.toString() + "row" + (r+1).toString();
    var location = document.getElementById(tID);
```

Edit: tID is the id of the divsthat are in the board element. 
The error I get is that location is a null =, when I call it.

The html and code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Play four-in-a-Row</title>
    <meta charset=ütf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="fourinarow.js"></script>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body onload="gameStart()">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="header" >
    <h1 id = "Main">Four-in-a-Row</h1>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id  = "animate">
    <div  id = "drop">
        <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Column 1" ondragover = "dragOver(event)" ondragleave = "dragLeave(event)" ondrop = "onDrop(event, 1)"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Column 2" ondragover = "dragOver(event)" ondragleave = "dragLeave(event)" ondrop = "onDrop(event, 2)"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Column 3" ondragover = "dragOver(event)" ondragleave = "dragLeave(event)" ondrop = "onDrop(event, 3)"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Column 4" ondragover = "dragOver(event)" ondragleave = "dragLeave(event)" ondrop = "onDrop(event, 4)"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Column 5" ondragover = "dragOver(event)" ondragleave = "dragLeave(event)" ondrop = "onDrop(event, 5)"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Column 6" ondragover = "dragOver(event)" ondragleave = "dragLeave(event)" ondrop = "onDrop(event, 6)"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Column 7" ondragover = "dragOver(event)" ondragleave = "dragLeave(event)" ondrop = "onDrop(event, 7)"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="board" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col1row1"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="co12row1"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col3row1"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col4row1"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col5row1"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col6row1"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col7row1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col1row2"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col2row2"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col3row2"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col4row2"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col5row2"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col6row2"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col7row2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col1row3"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col2row3"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col3row3"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col4row3"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col5row3"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col6row3"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col7row3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col1row4"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col2row4"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col3row4"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col4row4"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col5row4"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col6row4"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col7row4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col1row5"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col2row5"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col3row5"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col4row5"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col5row5"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col6row5"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col7row5"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "col-xs-1" ></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col7row6"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col7row6"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col7row6"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col7row6"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col7row6"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col7row6"></div>
            <div class = "square col-xs-1" id="col7row6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div  id= "piece">
            <!--
            <img src= "player_1.png" alt= "Player 1 piece" height = 15% width = 15% id = "player1" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Player one's piece" class ="player1 piece" draggable= "true" ondragstart ="dragStart(event)" >
            <img src= "player_2.png" alt= "Player 2 piece" height = 15% width = 15% id = "player2" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Player two's piece" class = "player2 piece" draggable= "true" ondragstart ="dragStart(event)"  >          
            -->
    </div>

<div id = alert class ="alert">
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="gameStart()" value="Reset" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" > </input>
</div>
</body>

<footer>
    <hr>
    <a href="../index.html">&lt;- Back to launch page</a>
    <hr>
    <p style= "text-align: right"> done by <br>Justin Michel <br> u14369852</p>
    <hr>
    <script>
    var map = new Array(6);
    var turnCount = 1;
    function clearBoard(){
        for(var r =0 ; r < 6; r++){
            map[r]= new Array(7);
            for(var c = 0; c < 7; c++){
                map[r][c] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    function boardSetup(){
        clearBoard();
        var board=document.getElementsByClassName("square");
        var blank = "<img src = blank.png alt=blank class=blank>";
        for(var x = 0; x < board.length; x++){
            <!--board[x].innerHTML = blank;-->
        }

        <!--document.getElementById("board").innerHTML=board;-->
        var temp = document.getElementsByClassName("blank");
        for(var z = 0; z < temp.length; z++){
            temp[z].className += " piece";
        }
    }

    function disPiece(){
        var piece1 = "<img src= player_1.png alt= Player1piece height = 15% width = 15% id = player1 data-toggle=tooltip title = 'Player one's piece' class = 'player1 piece' draggable= true ondragstart =dragStart(event) >";
        var piece2 = "<img src= player_2.png alt= Player2piece height = 15% width = 15% id = player2 data-toggle=tooltip title = 'Player two's piece' class = 'player2 piece' draggable= true ondragstart =dragStart(event)>";
        if(turnCount%2 == 1){
            document.getElementById("piece").innerHTML = piece1;
        }else if(turnCount %2 == 0){
            document.getElementById("piece").innerHTML = piece2;
        }
    }


    function gameStart(){
        boardSetup();
        disPiece();
        playercount = 1;
    }



    function checkWin(){
        var count;
        for(var r = 0; r< 3; r++){
            for(var c = 0; c < 4; c++){
                if(map[r][c] > 0){
                    count = 1;
                    for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++){
                        if(map[r][c + i]  == map[r][c]){
                            count++;
                        }
                        if(count == 4){
                            return map[r][c];
                        }
                        count = 1;
                        if(map[r + i][c]  == map[r][c]){
                            count++;
                        }
                        if(count == 4){
                            return map[r][c];
                        }
                        count = 1;
                        if(map[r + i ][c + i]  == map[r][c]){
                            count++;
                        }
                        if(count == 4){
                            return map[r][c];
                        }
                        count = 1;
                        if(map[r + i ][c - i]  == map[r][c]){
                            count++;
                        }
                        if(count == 4){
                            return map[r][c];
                        }
                        count = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }


    function getLowestRow(c){
        var r = -1;
        for(var i = 6; i >=0; i--){
            if(map[c][i] == 0){
                r = i;
                console.log("lowest row =" + i);
                break;
            }
        }
        return r;
    }



    function dropPiece(event,c){
        var alert = document.getElementById("alert");
        var r = getLowestRow(c);
        event.target.style.borderColor = "black";
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        alert.innerHTML = "";
        var tID = "col" + c.toString() + "row" + (r+1).toString();
        var location = document.getElementById(tID);
        if(r >= 0){

            <!-- Tests -->
            var test = "ece";
            var temp = document.getElementById("pi" + test);
            var temp2 = document.getElementById("piece");
            console.log("ID: " + temp2.id);
            console.log("ID: " + temp.id);
            console.log("ID: " + location.id);
            <!-- End tests-->
            var piece = document.createElement('img');
            assignImage(piece);
            document.getElementById("animate").appendChild(piece);
            var startPos = getOffset(event.target);
            var endPos = getOffset(location);
            piece.style.top =  startPos.top + 1;
            piece.style.left = startPos.left + 1;
            var pieceYPos = piece.style.top;
            var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
            function frame(){
                if(pieceYPos == endPos.top+1){
                    clearInterval(id);
                } else{
                    pieceYPos++;
                    piece.style.top = pieceYPos + "px";
                }
            }
            var par = document.getElementById("animate");
            par.removeChild(piece);
            var placePiece= document.createElement('img');
            assignImage(placePiece);
            location.appendChild(placePiece);
            var player = turnCount%2 == 0 ? 2: 1;
            map[c-1][r] = player;
        }else{
            alert.className = " alert-danger";
            alert.innerHTML = "<bold>ERORR</bold> Cannot drop into that column, it is full";
        }
    }

    function assignImage(content){
        if(turnCount%2 == 0){
            content.src = "player_2.png";
            content.alt = "Player 1 piece";
        }else{
            content.src = "player_1.png";
            content.alt = "Player 2 piece";
        }
        content.id="dropped";
        content.widthe="15%";
        content.height="15%";

    }

    function getOffset( el ) {
        var _x = 0;
        var _y = 0;
        while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
            _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
            _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
            el = el.offsetParent;
        }
        return { top: _y, left: _x };
    }       

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();     
    });

        //dragging

    function dragStart(event) {
        event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
    }

    function dragLeave(event){
        event.target.style.borderColor = "black";
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }

    function dragOver(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Test");
        if(turnCount%2 == 1){
            event.target.style.borderColor = "blue";
            event.target.style.backgroundColor = "#59F2F7"; 
        }else if(turnCount%2 == 0){
            event.target.style.borderColor = "red";
            event.target.style.backgroundColor = "#F75D59";
        }
    }

    function onDrop(event, c){
        var win = checkWin();
        if(win == 0){
            dropPiece(event,c);
            turnCount++;
            disPiece();
        }else{
            var player = turnCount%2 == 1? 1:2;
            alert("Player " + player + " wins!");
            gameStart();
        }
    }       
    </script>
</footer>
```

Comment: What the error you get ? the element that return is null ? can you tell us please what is the value of 'tID' when you try to find the element with this value ?

Comment: Don't use `<!-- -->` for comments in JavaScript. That's invalid syntax. Instead use `//` or `/* */`